# Is there a way to actually view the link for files being downloaed systemwide in a terminal?

Tags: 22.04

There are different utilities that can display the connections made by different processes system-wide such as `iftop`, but I haven't found one that would allow viewing the links to the actual files being downloaded.

Is there a way to get this kind of information using a terminal?

Comment: Start with `sudo lsof  -i`. Read `man lsof`

Comment: @waltinator thanks a lot, this is a very interesting command. looking into it asap ;)